# manage todonotes to insert figure in the margin

Tags: graphics, todonotes

How I can use `todonotes` package to insert figure in the margin? I want 3 parameters:

1. The name of the figure,
2. the width of the figure,
3. the caption (perhaps with `\tiny` or `\footnote` fonts).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

As far I now, there are not an easy method to include a figure in a to do note, but there are at least two easy alternatives: the `tufte-handout` class and/or a `\marginpar` with the aid of the `caption` package. A minimal working example (if you have also an image with the filename `gravatar.png`):

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gravatar.png}
\caption{A tufte margin figure}
\label{One}
\end{marginfigure}

See figure \ref{One} at margin. \lipsum[1] 

\lipsum[2] 

\marginpar{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{gravatar.png}
\captionof{figure}{\label{Two}A marginpar figure. 
Note that text width is in another scale here.}
}

\lipsum[3] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the second solution (\marginpar): she works almost fine with book class. Any solution with the todonotes package?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all you need to do is protect the `\includegraphics` macro. The following MWE works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\todoFig}[3]{
  \todo[noline]{
    \protect\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}\\
    \tiny #3
  }
}
\begin{document}
\todoFig{image.png}{1cm}{Small caption}
\end{document}
```